# how to add pagination by text box in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1

1)When we enter a product page number in text box it has to load that current page.
2)Display the remaining pages near to that text box.

Comment: can anybody help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $totalpage=$block->getLastPageNum(); //get total number of pages from block class.
        echo "Total Page is " . $totalpage;

    $currentUrl = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');
    $currentpage = $currentUrl->getCurrentUrl(); // get current url

?>
  <?php echo "Enter Page Number:" ?> 
<form class="custom_pager"><input type="text" name="pager" class="pager" onblur="goPage(this)"></form>
   <script>
            function goPage(obj)
            {
                var x = '<?php echo $currentpage; ?>';

                if(isNaN(obj.value)==true || Number(obj.value) >'<?php echo $totalpage; ?>') {
                    obj.style.borderColor = 'red';
                    obj.focus();
                    return false;

                }
                 else{
                window.location.href = updateQueryStringParameter(x, 'p', obj.value);
                } //provide an validation
            }   
            function updateQueryStringParameter(uri, key, value) {
              var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|$)", "i");
              var separator = uri.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?";
              if (uri.match(re)) {
                return uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
              }
              else {
                return uri + separator + key + "=" + value;
              }
            }//add or update a query string  parameters using these function. 
    </script>
```

Comment: the path to place these code is vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\list\toolbar.phtml